# Regular expression to enforce number is less than 1000 and has decimal points if any

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace price values in a string with a dummy value.

The validation will pass only if
the price is less than 1000 (price<1000)
the number has precisely two decimal places(if any)
there is at least one digit before the decimal point. (could be zero)

Valid numbers:

```
123,123.45,12 34,$12 34,$123,$1.23
```

Invalid numbers:

```
9999,99.999,99.9,1234 99
```

I tried this Regex

```
^\$?(\d{1,3})+([\s|\.]{1}[0-9][0-9])?
```

but it is still matching 12345
How can I resolve this issue?

Also, here is the sample text I want to edit with regex

Input:
I paid $199.99 for the purchase id `123456` and phone number `1234 3456 5678`.

desired output:
I paid dummy_price for the purchase id `123456` and phone number `1234 3456 5678`.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: 4 downvotes on a perfectly valid so question with a tried pattern and examples?

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for your time. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
(?<!\S)\$?\d{1,3}(?:[. ]\d\d)?(?!\S)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `\$?` Match an optional `$`
- `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
- `(?:[. ]\d\d)?` Optionally match either a `.` or   and 2 digits (you can also use `\s` but it could also match a newline
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HQE29m/1)

If you also don't want to match `99` in `1234 99` you can assert not 4 digits followed by a space to the left

```
(?<!\S)(?<!\d\d\d\d )\$?\d{1,3}(?:[. ]\d\d)?(?!\S)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/86RX39/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
\b\$?(\d{1,3})([\.][0-9][0-9])?\b
```

Your mistake here is that you used the qualifier `\d{1,3}` along with another qualifier `+`. In that case plus sign means `{1,}`. Another issue is that this construction `[\s|\.]` means you want the vertical sign `|` to be your separator along with space and dot. When you put `|` in square brackets is doesn't anymore mean choice option like in normal brackets.
I put the `\b` which means word boundary.

Answer (score 0):

`\b\d{1,3}([\s.]\d{0,2})?\b`

Explanation:

- Word separator
- 1 to 3 digits
- Optional: space or dot, then 0 to 2 digits
- Word separator

Answer (score 0):

In your valid cases, `12 34` and `$12 34` should not be present, (according to your definition they are not a number). I think you intended to put `.` instead of space in valid cases, so I assumed this way...

Then you could try this :

```
import re

valids = ['123', '123.45', '12.34', '$12.34', '$123', '$1.23']
invalids = ['9999', '99.999', '99.9', '1234 99']

pattern = r'^\$?\d{1,3}(\.\d{2})?$'

print([bool(re.match(pattern, item)) for item in valids])
print([bool(re.match(pattern, item)) for item in invalids])
```

Output :

```
[True, True, True, True, True, True]
[False, False, False, False]
```

Explanation :

`\$?` allowed dollar sign to be optional at the first position.

`\d{1,3}` should be less than 1000.

`(\.\d{2})?` decimal part is optional but if it present, 2 digits are allowed.

`$` end of the string